# How to add page numbers to a dynamically sized PDF generated from XSLT without using extensions or scripts?

Tags: xml, pdf, xslt

I'm generating a PDF from an XSLT file using an API itext sharp, and I need to add page numbers to the resulting PDF. However, the size of the document varies, and I can't estimate the number of pages in advance. Additionally, I can't use any extensions or JavaScript scripts to achieve this.

I've tried using XSL-FO to define a footer with page numbers, but it doesn't work for dynamically sized documents. Is there a way to add page numbers to a dynamically sized PDF without using extensions or scripts? If so, what approach should I take?Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: In what way do you believe that FOP/XSL FO does not work for dynamically sized documents?